# How to implement ACRA with custom URL

Tags: android, web, acra

1. I want to send the mail of Crash report in background but unable to send because it is using **ACTION_SEND**
   I am using code: `formKey = "", mailTo = "abc@gmail.com"`
2. How can i make the url where the reports can be save to my own server, If any dummy url available to store or any open source database can be used. Please recommend.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a custom class that implements ReportSender?

Comment: @HariKrishnan not yet. May you please send me a reference link.

Comment: ok. please see the below answer. you can use those two classes to manage crashes.

Comment: @HariKrishnan Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this custom class:

```java
public class AcraCustomSender implements ReportSender {

    Context activity;

    @Override
    public void send(Context context, CrashReportData errorContent) throws ReportSenderException {
        activity=context;
        String crashReport = "";

        try {
            JSONObject object =  errorContent.toJSON();
            Log.e("acra", object.toString());
            crashReport = object.toString();


        }catch (JSONReportBuilder.JSONReportException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //the string crashreport contains your crash log. you can pass it to your own backend.

    }
}
```

Create another class for your application:

```java
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        try {
            ACRA.init(this);
            AcraCustomSender yourSender = new AcraCustomSender();
            ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(yourSender);
            super.onCreate();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, whenever app crashes you can get it in AcraCustomSender class, and do whatever you want to do(like sending to your own DB)